# Why does Worf behave more like Klingon than Human given that he was raised by human parents?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, klingon, worf

If a Chinese kid is raised by white American parents, he will most probably grow up to behave more like the white parents than Chinese. This is even more so for an alien raised by humans. At least whites and Chinese are humans.

How can Worf be so much more Klingon than human?

I may have missed out some episodes that explain this unusual phenomenon. In the episodes I watched, Worf behaved more like a Klingon than human.

Comment: It's worth noting that many characters, sometimes including Worf himself, feel that Worf is more human than Klingon.

Comment: I do not get this impression from the episodes I watched so far. He is aggressive like a normal Klingon.

Comment: It's mostly other Klingons who go out of their way to say it. Other Starfleet members usually don't care whether you're more X than Y.

Comment: I wouldn't say he's aggressive "like a normal Klingon."  Normal Klingons frequently go out of their way to provoke a fight, just to test their strength.  Worf is certainly prepared to fight, and takes great pride in participating in Klingon rituals that often involve violence of some kind, but he doesn't pick a fight that he doesn't need to.  That's evidence of his human upbringing right there.